# Persist information from controller to Thymeleaf and then send it to another controller (thymeleaf and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working in a recovery password form with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf, the process is that the backend sends a link to the user with a token, this token is saved in a DB with the user information. The user clicks the link and the backend validate the token, if it's correct it redirects with the user information to the "new pass" form where the user has to introduce a new password and repeat it. When the user introduces the passwords and press save, it sends the information to the back end, with the userId it searches the register and changes the password.

In the controller where I validate the token when the user presses the link, I search the users' information and I build and usersRecoverPassDto with the userId and the passwords null and organize the model object to send it to the "new pass" form like this:

```
PasswordManagmentPostDto passManagment = new PasswordManagmentPostDto();

passManagment.setUserId(userId);

model.addAttribute ("passInfo", passManagment);
```

In the "new pass" form I received the correct information:

```
passInfo={
 userId: 123456,
 newPassword: null,
 repeatePassword: null
}
```

The "new pass" form I code is like this:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/password/recovery}" th:object="${passInfo}" method="post">
  <div class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 position-reNew pass:</label>
    <input type="password" th:field="*{newPassword}" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 position-relative form-group">
    <label for="repeatePass" class="mr-sm-2">Repeat pass:</label>
    <input type="password" th:field="*{repeatNewPassword}" placeholder="Repita contraseña" class="form-control"/>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 mt-3 position-relative form-group">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" class="inputButton btn btn-success "/>
  </div>
</form>
```

I enter the two passwords and press the button Save but in the controller, I receive the next object:

```
passInfo={
 userId: null,
 newPassword: password,
 repeatePassword: password
}
```

The userId parameter is just a parameter that passes without any modification and without being shown but I don't know how to persist this value from the controller to the view and then to the other controller.

I trayed adding another input to the new pass form:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{userId}" th:value="*{userId}" placeholder="userId" class="form-control"/>
```

And I did nothing with this input, just put the two passwords and press the save button and it worked, I received the object with the correct information.

Of course, the userId parameter must not be shown in the form or modified.

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

**OLD ANSWER**

Use a `hidden` input:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId" th:value="*{userId}" />
```

This is part of what `hidden` inputs are for, to maintain data that should be sent back to the controller, but isn't something for the user to see / change.

**NEW ANSWER**

Per our discussion in the comments, it sounds like the appropriate approach is to retain the user's token on the front end. Pass that token to the controller when submitting the form, then look up the user by that token to reset the password.

Comment: But with `hidden`, I can inspect the page (F12 for Chrome), you can get the userId and modified it and modified the query to change the password:

`<input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId" value="1234">`

Comment: Correct. You can't retain the `userId` without somehow managing it on the front end as well. As far as I know that just isn't possible. What harm is it for someone to know the `userId`?

Comment: But the problem is that I can change the userId and when I press the save button, I can change another user password

Comment: If this is to change the password for the currently logged in user, just grab the user id of the current user in the controller.

Comment: Is not to change the password in the current session, for example, you try to login to any web site and you are in the login page, you forgot your password, you press the "forget password button", you submit your mail address and they send you an email with a link to restore you password so you enter the new password and in the DB the modified the password so, during the restore password process you aren't logged in.

Comment: In that case, I think you would use the user's username or email address, not a user id. I think this is a larger problem, because it seems you're resetting the password directly within your application rather than using something like an email link to change the password.

Comment: One thing that I can do but I don't know if is totally correct is:
I have a PasswordManagmentController where I receive all the requests from this process and a PasswordManagmentService where I manage the logic from the PasswordManagmentController. I have to methods, the first one is used when the user presses the link and I verify the token and return the info to the "new pass" form. The other method is when I submit the new password, the possible solution is to save the userId as a global variable and use it in both methods, is this a good practice?

Comment: I use the email to validate that the user exists and that the token is correct, then I redirect to the "new pass" form with the userId because is better to find by id the user information in the DB to change the password

Comment: Does the token not contain the user id?

Comment: The process is like this:
forgot pass button -> enter email to validate that user exists and generate token -> send email to the user with the link to restore password -> open link and validate token -> redirect to new pass form with userId -> enter new pass and press save button -> search in the DB the user info and change password

Comment: No, the token doesn't contain the userId, the token is saved in a table with relation to the users' table

Comment: In that case, I would think you would retain the token in the front end, then in the controller look up the user id that way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to try that, is like the same of saving the userId as a global variable in the backend.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the changes we've talked about here.